# running an application on vps

Tags: c#, selenium, vps

I have just finished a project , for short an Instagram robot for following and other tasks which is written in c# and selenium, for make it more practical and prevent from cracking and stealing my code I would like to run it on a virtual server because it needs a single system to work continuously for running.

As I don't have any experience in working with VPS, I need some hints, first is my approach correct? can I execute my application in a virtual server like a personal computer?

Moreover can I use a VPS as a host? like some parts of my application run on the VPS and some parts run on the other host?I mean could they be connected together? something like a panel(run on host) which users are able to do different settings on their robots(run on vps).

thanks for any tips , article or advise in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you should do is connect to a VPS using the windows Remote Desktop application.
then it's basically like a personal computer, you can run your robot and close the Remote Desktop application and it keeps running.